# Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations' after installing angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, yarn-v2

Upon lauching my application I get the error:

Cannot find module '@angular/platform-browser/animations'

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "oscar-app-ihm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.43.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028346/cannot-find-module-angular-platform-browser-animations) mentions using npm to reinstall the angular/cli.

Unfortunately I cannot use npm commands, as I get this error:

npm ERR! Unexpected token '.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sc72096\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-09T08_00_19_312Z-debug-0.log

We use Yarn to install dependencies, so i ran yarn add @angular/cli, and add @angular/platform-browser.
This unfortunately did not fix the issue.

I am running the command in the intellij console at the root of my application.

This issue seems to have appeared after I installed angular material, using yarn add @angular/material

If I run yarn install, to install all my dependencies, I get:
yarn install v1.22.5
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

I actually was not installing the dependencies in the right folder, I needed to go one folder deeper.

Then I ran ng update @angular/cli @angular/core to upgrade all dependencies

my package JSON now looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "oscar-app-ihm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/material": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.43.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.43.0",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  }
}
```

The dependencies with version 15.0.1 have been upgraded to 15.0.4